# How to drop rows of Pandas DataFrame whose value in a certain column is NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, nan

I have this DataFrame and want only the records whose EPS column is not NaN:

```
                 STK_ID  EPS  cash
STK_ID RPT_Date                   
601166 20111231  601166  NaN   NaN
600036 20111231  600036  NaN    12
600016 20111231  600016  4.3   NaN
601009 20111231  601009  NaN   NaN
601939 20111231  601939  2.5   NaN
000001 20111231  000001  NaN   NaN
```

...i.e. something like `df.drop(....)` to get this resulting dataframe:

```
                  STK_ID  EPS  cash
STK_ID RPT_Date                   
600016 20111231  600016  4.3   NaN
601939 20111231  601939  2.5   NaN
```

How do I do that?

Comment: dropna: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: `df.dropna(subset = ['column1_name', 'column2_name', 'column3_name'])`

Comment: `df.dropna(subset = ['EPS'])`

Comment: Another ruthless way if you hate NaN so much `df = df.dropna(subset=df.columns.values)` and you find there are no NaN anywhere

Answer (score 1606, accepted):

Don't drop, just take the rows where EPS is not NA:

```py
df = df[df['EPS'].notna()]
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to indexing and copying over dropping?

Comment: @wes-mckinney could please let me know if dropna () is a better choice over pandas.notnull in this case ? If so, then why ?

Comment: This does not catch line 3 where EPS is 4.3 (valid) and cash is NaN. I expect OP to want to drop that one too.

Comment: we can also use `df.dropna(subset=['EPS'])`

Comment: `dropna` is actually faster if there are multiple columns.

Answer (score 1212):

This question is already resolved, but...

...also consider the solution suggested by Wouter in [his original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-of-certain-column-is-nan/13434501#comment18328797_13413590). The ability to handle missing data, including `dropna()`, is built into pandas explicitly. Aside from potentially improved performance over doing it manually, these functions also come with a variety of options which may be useful.

```
In [24]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3))

In [25]: df.iloc[::2,0] = np.nan; df.iloc[::4,1] = np.nan; df.iloc[::3,2] = np.nan;

In [26]: df
Out[26]:
          0         1         2
0       NaN       NaN       NaN
1  2.677677 -1.466923 -0.750366
2       NaN  0.798002 -0.906038
3  0.672201  0.964789       NaN
4       NaN       NaN  0.050742
5 -1.250970  0.030561 -2.678622
6       NaN  1.036043       NaN
7  0.049896 -0.308003  0.823295
8       NaN       NaN  0.637482
9 -0.310130  0.078891       NaN
```

---

```
In [27]: df.dropna()     #drop all rows that have any NaN values
Out[27]:
          0         1         2
1  2.677677 -1.466923 -0.750366
5 -1.250970  0.030561 -2.678622
7  0.049896 -0.308003  0.823295
```

---

```
In [28]: df.dropna(how='all')     #drop only if ALL columns are NaN
Out[28]:
          0         1         2
1  2.677677 -1.466923 -0.750366
2       NaN  0.798002 -0.906038
3  0.672201  0.964789       NaN
4       NaN       NaN  0.050742
5 -1.250970  0.030561 -2.678622
6       NaN  1.036043       NaN
7  0.049896 -0.308003  0.823295
8       NaN       NaN  0.637482
9 -0.310130  0.078891       NaN
```

---

```
In [29]: df.dropna(thresh=2)   #Drop row if it does not have at least two values that are **not** NaN
Out[29]:
          0         1         2
1  2.677677 -1.466923 -0.750366
2       NaN  0.798002 -0.906038
3  0.672201  0.964789       NaN
5 -1.250970  0.030561 -2.678622
7  0.049896 -0.308003  0.823295
9 -0.310130  0.078891       NaN
```

---

```
In [30]: df.dropna(subset=[1])   #Drop only if NaN in specific column (as asked in the question)
Out[30]:
          0         1         2
1  2.677677 -1.466923 -0.750366
2       NaN  0.798002 -0.906038
3  0.672201  0.964789       NaN
5 -1.250970  0.030561 -2.678622
6       NaN  1.036043       NaN
7  0.049896 -0.308003  0.823295
9 -0.310130  0.078891       NaN
```

There are also other options (See docs at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), including dropping columns instead of rows.

Pretty handy!

Comment: you can also use `df.dropna(subset = ['column_name'])`. Hope that saves at least one person the extra 5 seconds of 'what am I doing wrong'. Great answer, +1

Comment: @JamesTobin, I just spent 20 minutes to write a function for that! [The official documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) was very cryptic: "Labels along other axis to consider, e.g. if you are dropping rows these would be a list of columns to include". I was unable to understand, what they meant...

Comment: ```df.dropna(subset = ['column_name'])``` is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: This answer is super helpful but in case it isn't clear to anyone reading what options are useful in which situations, I've put together a dropna FAQ post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62444845/4909087). Hope this helps people who are struggling to apply `dropna` to their specific need.

Comment: +1 this answer also seems to help avoid having `SettingWithCopyWarning` later when you use `df.dropna(subset = ['column_name'], inplace=True)`

Comment: @Aman Hi, could you take a look at this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70954791/identifying-statistical-outliers-with-pandas-groupby-and-reduce-rows-into-diffe

Answer (score 162):

You can use this:

```
df.dropna(subset=['EPS'], how='all', inplace=True)
```

Comment: `how='all'` is redundant here, because you subsetting dataframe only with one field so both `'all'` and `'any'` will have the same effect.

Comment: @AntonProtopopov **IMPORTANT:** `how='all'` is NOT redundant. 

Define a simple dataframe: `df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [10, None], "b": [None, 10]})`

Doing `df.dropna(subset=['a', 'b'], how='all')` leaves the dataframe intact (as there aren't rows where both columns are `Nan`, while dropping that parameter returns an empty dataframe.

Comment: @EnriqueOrtizCasillas we were talking about that specific case. In the comment I mentioned that it's only about **one** field. For that `'all'` and `'any'` are the same. In general case it depends on what is your ultimate goal.

In your example you are selecting by two columns - that's a different case.

Answer (score 150):

I know this has already been answered, but just for the sake of a purely pandas solution to this specific question as opposed to the general description from Aman (which was wonderful) and in case anyone else happens upon this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = df[pd.notnull(df['EPS'])]
```

Comment: Actually, the specific answer would be: `df.dropna(subset=['EPS'])` (based on the general description of Aman, of course this does also work)

Comment: `notnull` is also what Wes (author of Pandas) suggested in his comment on another answer.

Comment: This maybe a noob question. But when I do a df[pd.notnull(...) or df.dropna the index gets dropped. So if  there was a null value in row-index 10 in a df of length 200. The dataframe after running the drop function has index values from 1 to 9 and then 11 to  200. Anyway to "re-index" it

Comment: you could also do `df[pd.notnull(df[df.columns[INDEX]])]` where `INDEX` would be the numbered column if you don't know name

Comment: For some reason this answer worked for me and the `df.dropna(subset=['column name']` didnt.

Answer (score 67):

> ### How to drop rows of Pandas DataFrame whose value in a certain column is NaN

This is an old question which has been beaten to death but I do believe there is some more useful information to be surfaced on this thread. Read on if you're looking for the answer to any of the following questions:

- Can I drop rows if any of its values have NaNs? What about if all of them are NaN?
- Can I only look at NaNs in specific columns when dropping rows?
- Can I drop rows with a specific count of NaN values?
- How do I drop columns instead of rows?
- I tried all of the options above but my DataFrame just won't update!

---

## [`DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html): Usage, and Examples

It's already been said that `df.dropna` is the canonical method to drop NaNs from DataFrames, but there's nothing like a few visual cues to help along the way.

```
# Setup
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [np.nan, 2, 3, 4],  
    'B': [np.nan, np.nan, 2, 3], 
    'C': [np.nan]*3 + [3]}) 

df                      
     A    B    C
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  2.0  NaN  NaN
2  3.0  2.0  NaN
3  4.0  3.0  3.0
```

Below is a detail of the most important arguments and how they work, arranged in an FAQ format.

---

### Can I drop rows if any of its values have NaNs? What about if all of them are NaN?

This is where the `how=...` argument comes in handy. It can be one of

- `'any'` (default) - drops rows if at least one column has NaN
- `'all'` - drops rows only if all of its columns have NaNs

<!_ ->

```
# Removes all but the last row since there are no NaNs 
df.dropna()

     A    B    C
3  4.0  3.0  3.0

# Removes the first row only
df.dropna(how='all')

     A    B    C
1  2.0  NaN  NaN
2  3.0  2.0  NaN
3  4.0  3.0  3.0
```

> **Note**
> If you just want to see which rows are null (IOW, if you want a
> boolean mask of rows), use
> [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html):
>
> ```
> df.isna()
>
>        A      B      C
> 0   True   True   True
> 1  False   True   True
> 2  False  False   True
> 3  False  False  False
>
> df.isna().any(axis=1)
>
> 0     True
> 1     True
> 2     True
> 3    False
> dtype: bool
> ```
>
> To get the inversion of this result, use
> [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html#pandas.DataFrame.notna)
> instead.

---

### Can I only look at NaNs in specific columns when dropping rows?

This is a use case for the `subset=[...]` argument.

Specify a list of columns (or indexes with `axis=1`) to tells pandas you only want to look at these columns (or rows with `axis=1`) when dropping rows (or columns with `axis=1`.

```
# Drop all rows with NaNs in A
df.dropna(subset=['A'])

     A    B    C
1  2.0  NaN  NaN
2  3.0  2.0  NaN
3  4.0  3.0  3.0

# Drop all rows with NaNs in A OR B
df.dropna(subset=['A', 'B'])

     A    B    C
2  3.0  2.0  NaN
3  4.0  3.0  3.0
```

---

### Can I drop rows with a specific count of NaN values?

This is a use case for the `thresh=...` argument. Specify the minimum number of NON-NULL values as an integer.

```
df.dropna(thresh=1)  

     A    B    C
1  2.0  NaN  NaN
2  3.0  2.0  NaN
3  4.0  3.0  3.0

df.dropna(thresh=2)

     A    B    C
2  3.0  2.0  NaN
3  4.0  3.0  3.0

df.dropna(thresh=3)

     A    B    C
3  4.0  3.0  3.0
```

The thing to note here is you need to specify how many NON-NULL values you want to *keep*, rather than how many NULL values you want to *drop*. This is a pain point for new users.

Luckily the fix is easy: if you have a count of NULL values, simply subtract it from the column size to get the correct thresh argument for the function.

```
required_min_null_values_to_drop = 2 # drop rows with at least 2 NaN
df.dropna(thresh=df.shape[1] - required_min_null_values_to_drop + 1)

     A    B    C
2  3.0  2.0  NaN
3  4.0  3.0  3.0
```

---

### How do I drop columns instead of rows?

Use the `axis=...` argument, it can be `axis=0` or `axis=1`.

Tells the function whether you want to drop rows (`axis=0`) or drop columns (`axis=1`).

```
df.dropna()

     A    B    C
3  4.0  3.0  3.0

# All columns have rows, so the result is empty.
df.dropna(axis=1)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3]

# Here's a different example requiring the column to have all NaN rows
# to be dropped. In this case no columns satisfy the condition.
df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')

     A    B    C
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  2.0  NaN  NaN
2  3.0  2.0  NaN
3  4.0  3.0  3.0

# Here's a different example requiring a column to have at least 2 NON-NULL
# values. Column C has less than 2 NON-NULL values, so it should be dropped.
df.dropna(axis=1, thresh=2)

     A    B
0  NaN  NaN
1  2.0  NaN
2  3.0  2.0
3  4.0  3.0
```

---

### I tried all of the options above but my DataFrame just won't update!

`dropna`, like most other functions in the pandas API returns a new DataFrame (a copy of the original with changes) as the result, so you should assign it back if you want to see changes.

```
df.dropna(...) # wrong
df.dropna(..., inplace=True) # right, but not recommended
df = df.dropna(...) # right
```

---

## Reference

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

> ```
> DataFrame.dropna(
>     self, axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)
> ```
>
> [image]

Answer (score 43):

**Simplest of all solutions:**

```
filtered_df = df[df['EPS'].notnull()]
```

> The above solution is way better than using np.isfinite()

Answer (score 32):

**Simple and easy way**

`df.dropna(subset=['EPS'],inplace=True)`

source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: `inplace=True` is a bizarre topic, and has no effect on `DataFrame.dropna()`. See: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529

Comment: How does this answer differ from @Joe's answer? Also, inplace is will be deprecated eventually, best not to use it at all.

Answer (score 26):

You could use dataframe method [notnull](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html) or inverse of [isnull](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html), or [numpy.isnan](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html):

```
In [332]: df[df.EPS.notnull()]
Out[332]:
   STK_ID  RPT_Date  STK_ID.1  EPS  cash
2  600016  20111231    600016  4.3   NaN
4  601939  20111231    601939  2.5   NaN


In [334]: df[~df.EPS.isnull()]
Out[334]:
   STK_ID  RPT_Date  STK_ID.1  EPS  cash
2  600016  20111231    600016  4.3   NaN
4  601939  20111231    601939  2.5   NaN


In [347]: df[~np.isnan(df.EPS)]
Out[347]:
   STK_ID  RPT_Date  STK_ID.1  EPS  cash
2  600016  20111231    600016  4.3   NaN
4  601939  20111231    601939  2.5   NaN
```

Answer (score 15):

yet another solution which uses the fact that `np.nan != np.nan`:

```
In [149]: df.query("EPS == EPS")
Out[149]:
                 STK_ID  EPS  cash
STK_ID RPT_Date
600016 20111231  600016  4.3   NaN
601939 20111231  601939  2.5   NaN
```

Answer (score 4):

Another version:

```
df[~df['EPS'].isna()]
```

Comment: Why use this over `Series.notna()` ?

Answer (score 4):

The following method worked for me. It would help if none of the above methods work:

```
df[df['colum_name'].str.len() >= 1]
```

The basic idea is that you pick up the record only if the length strength is greater than 1. This is especially useful if you are dealing with string data

Best!

Comment: This only works for objects columns: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values! if your columns is float or int

Answer (score 3):

It  may be added at that '&' can be used to add additional conditions e.g.

```
df = df[(df.EPS > 2.0) & (df.EPS <4.0)]
```

Notice that when evaluating the statements, pandas needs parenthesis.

Comment: Sorry, but OP want someting else. Btw, your code is wrong, return `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`. You need add parenthesis - `df = df[(df.EPS > 2.0) & (df.EPS <4.0)]`, but also it  is not answer for this question.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) inside [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
In [4]: df.query('EPS.notna().values')
Out[4]: 
                 STK_ID.1  EPS  cash
STK_ID RPT_Date                     
600016 20111231    600016  4.3   NaN
601939 20111231    601939  2.5   NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

In datasets having large number of columns its even better to see how many columns contain null values and how many don't.

```
print("No. of columns containing null values")
print(len(df.columns[df.isna().any()]))

print("No. of columns not containing null values")
print(len(df.columns[df.notna().all()]))

print("Total no. of columns in the dataframe")
print(len(df.columns))
```

For example in my dataframe it contained 82 columns, of which 19 contained at least one null value.

Further you can also **automatically remove cols and rows** depending on which has more null values
Here is the code which does this intelligently:

```
df = df.drop(df.columns[df.isna().sum()>len(df.columns)],axis = 1)
df = df.dropna(axis = 0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Note:** Above code removes all of your null values. If you want null values, process them before.

Comment: There is Another Question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36226083/8127390)

Comment: This question has really been squeezed out of questioning, get it? :)

Answer (score 0):

### `dropna` vs boolean indexing

If we look at the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2a953cf80b77e4348bf50ed724f8abc0d814d9dd/pandas/core/frame.py#L6421-L6436), under the hood, `dropna()` is precisely `notna()` + boolean indexing. Depending on what was passed to `how=`, `all()` or `any()` is called to reduce the `notna` mask into a Series.

The main difference is that with `dropna()`, you specify the rows to *drop*, while with the boolean indexing, you look you specify the rows to *keep*, which is logically the opposite problem. So depending on the use-case, it might be more intuitive to approach the problem of dropping rows with NaN values from the perspective of *keeping* non-NaN rows or *dropping* NaN rows.

To sum up, the following are True for any dataframe `df`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, pd.NA], "B": [pd.NA, 'a', 'b'], "C": [pd.NA, 10, 20]})

cols = ['A', 'B']
x1 = df.dropna(subset=cols, how='any')      # specify which rows to drop
y1 = df[df[cols].notna().all(axis=1)]       # specify which rows to keep
assert x1.equals(y1)

x2 = df.dropna(subset=cols, how='all')
y2 = df[df[cols].notna().any(axis=1)]
assert x2.equals(y2)
```

Also, `thresh=` argument is equivalent to checking if the number of non-NaN values in each row is not less than `thresh` value; in other words, the following is True:

```py
thresh = 2
x3 = df[df[cols].count(axis=1) >= thresh]
y3 = df.dropna(subset=cols, thresh=thresh)
assert x3.equals(y3)
```

---

Now, if the task is to simply drop rows with NaN values, then `dropna()` is most intuitive and *should* be used. However, since mask + boolean indexing is more general, you can define a more complex mask and filter using it.

For example, say, you want to drop rows where either column `A` value is NaN or there are more than 1 NaN value. This requires 2 function calls using `dropna`. However, with boolean indexing, you can filter using a single mask.

```py
msk = (df.isna().sum(axis=1) > 1) | df['A'].isna()
df = df[~msk]
```

---

On a side note, if you get `SettingWithCopyWarning` when you modify a dataframe constructed via boolean indexing, consider setting copy-on-write mode to True (read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76312603/19123103)).

```py
pd.set_option('mode.copy_on_write', True)   # turn on copy-on-write

msk = (df.isna().sum(axis=1) > 1) | df['A'].isna()
df1 = df[~msk]
df1['new_col'] = 1                          # <--- no SettingWithCopyWarning
```

Answer (score 0):

Those who want to make dropna part of a feature engineering / scikit-learn pipeline, can use `DropMissingData` from Feature-engine.

The following will drop all rows with nan in a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from feature_engine.imputation import DropMissingData
X = pd.DataFrame(dict(
       x1 = [np.nan,1,1,0,np.nan],
       x2 = ["a", np.nan, "b", np.nan, "a"],
       ))
dmd = DropMissingData()
dmd.fit(X)
dmd.transform(X)
```

The result of the former block is:

```
    x1 x2
2  1.0  b
```

To drop rows with nan only in a specific column, for example x2:

```
dmd = DropMissingData(variables = "x2")
dmd.fit(X)
dmd.transform(X)
```

The former block returns the following:

```
    x1 x2
0  NaN  a
2  1.0  b
4  NaN  a
```

Finally, from within a Pipeline:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

from feature_engine.imputation import DropMissingData
from feature_engine.pipeline import Pipeline

pipe = Pipeline(
    [
        ("drop", DropMissingData()),
        ("enc", OrdinalEncoder()),
        ("lasso", Lasso(random_state=10)),
    ]
).set_output(transform="pandas")

pipe.fit(X, y)
preds_pipe = pipe.predict(X)
```

More details in Feature-engine's [dropna](https://feature-engine.trainindata.com/en/latest/user_guide/imputation/DropMissingData.html) documentation

Answer (score -4):

you can try with:

```
df['EPS'].dropna()
```