# Remove rows from dataframe that sum to zero

Tags: python, pandas

I have already removed rows where a company was not charged anything for a given `period` (e.g., a row where `revenue` == 0).

Here is an example of the billing data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'account_id': ['111','111','222','333','666','666','111','222','333','666','666'],
    'company': ['initech','initech','jackson steinem & co','ingen','enron','enron','initech','jackson steinem & co','ingen','enron','enron'],
    'billing_type': ['subscription','discount','subscription','subscription','subscription','discount','subscription','subscription','subscription','subscription','discount'],
    'period': ['2012-10-31','2012-10-31','2012-10-31','2012-10-31','2012-10-31','2012-10-31','2012-11-30','2012-11-30','2012-11-30','2012-11-30','2012-11-30'],
    'revenue':[39.95,-39.95,199.95,299.95,499.95,-499.95,39.95,199.95,299.95,499.95,-499.95]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['period'],format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

This yields a dataframe like so:

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
   account_id  billing_type               company     period  revenue
0         111  subscription               initech 2012-10-31    39.95
1         111      discount               initech 2012-10-31   -39.95
2         222  subscription  jackson steinem & co 2012-10-31   199.95
3         333  subscription                 ingen 2012-10-31   299.95
4         666  subscription                 enron 2012-10-31   499.95
5         666      discount                 enron 2012-10-31  -499.95
6         111  subscription               initech 2012-11-30    39.95
7         222  subscription  jackson steinem & co 2012-11-30   199.95
8         333  subscription                 ingen 2012-11-30   299.95
9         666  subscription                 enron 2012-11-30   499.95
10        666      discount                 enron 2012-11-30  -499.95
```

What I need to do is remove the rows where `revenue` adds up to zero for a given `company`/`period`. So, for instance, I need to remove all of Enron's rows but only the October 2012 period for Initech:

```
In [17]: df.groupby(['company','period'])['revenue'].sum()
Out[17]:
company               period
enron                 2012-10-31      0.00
                      2012-11-30      0.00
ingen                 2012-10-31    299.95
                      2012-11-30    299.95
initech               2012-10-31      0.00
                      2012-11-30     39.95
jackson steinem & co  2012-10-31    199.95
                      2012-11-30    199.95
```

A [number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573052/pandas-dataframe-how-do-i-remove-all-columns-and-rows-that-sum-to-0) of [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649693/drop-rows-with-all-zeros-in-pandas-data-frame) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873175/pandas-remove-rows-based-on-combinations-of-nan-values) address similar cases, and I have not been able to find anything that exactly helps/explains how to accomplish this request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) to make a frame-size mask you could then use to select:

```
>>> keep = df.groupby(["company", "period"])["revenue"].transform(sum) != 0
>>> df.loc[keep]
  account_id  billing_type               company     period  revenue
2        222  subscription  jackson steinem & co 2012-10-31   199.95
3        333  subscription                 ingen 2012-10-31   299.95
6        111  subscription               initech 2012-11-30    39.95
7        222  subscription  jackson steinem & co 2012-11-30   199.95
8        333  subscription                 ingen 2012-11-30   299.95
```

This works because `transform` takes the groupby result and "broadcasts" it back up to the main index:

```
>>> df.groupby(["company", "period"])["revenue"].transform(sum)
0       0.00
1       0.00
2     199.95
3     299.95
4       0.00
5       0.00
6      39.95
7     199.95
8     299.95
9       0.00
10      0.00
dtype: float64
>>> df.groupby(["company", "period"])["revenue"].transform(sum) != 0
0     False
1     False
2      True
3      True
4     False
5     False
6      True
7      True
8      True
9     False
10    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. A big thanks to for including an explanation of the documentation using my example data!!