# removing NA values from a DataFrame in Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import statistics

df=print(pd.read_csv('001.csv',keep_default_na=False, na_values=[""]))
print(df)
```

I am using this code to create a data frame which has no NA values. I have couple of CSV files and I want to calculate Mean of one of the columns - sulfate. This column has many 'NA' values, which I am trying to exclude. Even after using the above code, 'NA's aren't excluded from the data frame. 
Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should import the .csv file as it is and then manipulate the data frame.
Then, you can use any of the methods below.

```
foo[foo.notnull()]
```

or

```
foo.dropna()
```

Comment: thanks for replying but i get this error:    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'notnull'

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 :**

```
 df[['A','C']].apply(lambda x: my_func(x) if(np.all(pd.notnull(x[1]))) else x, axis = 1)
```

Use **pandas notnull**

**Method 2 :**

```
df = df[np.isfinite(df['EPS'])]
```

**Method 3 :** Using dropna [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-of-certain-column-is-nan/13434501#comment18328797_13413590)

```
In [24]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3))

In [25]: df.ix[::2,0] = np.nan; df.ix[::4,1] = np.nan; df.ix[::3,2] = np.nan;

In [26]: df
Out[26]:
          0         1         2
0       NaN       NaN       NaN
1  2.677677 -1.466923 -0.750366
2       NaN  0.798002 -0.906038
3  0.672201  0.964789       NaN
4       NaN       NaN  0.050742
5 -1.250970  0.030561 -2.678622
6       NaN  1.036043       NaN
7  0.049896 -0.308003  0.823295
8       NaN       NaN  0.637482
9 -0.310130  0.078891       NaN

In [27]: df.dropna()     #drop all rows that have any NaN values
Out[27]:
          0         1         2
1  2.677677 -1.466923 -0.750366
5 -1.250970  0.030561 -2.678622
7  0.049896 -0.308003  0.823295
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but i keep on getting this error on using all of the above methods  - 'df.dropna(subset = ['sulfate'])'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dropna'  I tried to replace NA with '0' so that I can directly get a mean   -'clean = df.replace('NA', 0)'

Comment: Still I get this Attribute Error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: I can't attach here, but I am providing a sample:                                  Date         sulfate nitrate ID
* 1/1/2003 NA NA 1
* 1/2/2003 NA NA 1
* 1/3/2003 NA NA 1
* 1/4/2003 NA NA 1
* 1/5/2003 NA NA 1

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error until I added `axis=0` and `how='any'`.

```
df=df.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
columsMissng=[]
for i in columns:
   c=df.loc[df[i] == '?', i].count();
   columsMissng.append((i,c));
c=0
dropcolumsMissng=[]
for i in columsMissng:
    if i[1]>20000:
        count=count+1;
        dropcolumsMissng.append(i[0])
newDF=df.drop(columns=dropcolumsMissng)
```

In place of `'?'` you can put any value you want to count and `if i[1]>20000:`
you can put your threshold like 50% of data or anything you want.

In case you want to remove 'NaN'

```
c=newDF.columns.values
dropcolumsMissng=[]

for i in columns:
    num_nans = len(newDF) - newDF[i].count()
    if num_nans>20000:
        dropcolumsMissng.append(i)
newDF=newDF.drop(columns=dropcolumsMissng)
```