# pandas How to store rows dropped using `drop_duplicates`?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Note: See EDIT below.**

I need to keep a log of all rows dropped from my df, but I'm not sure how to capture them. The log should be a data frame that I can update for each `.drop` or `.drop_duplicates`operation. Here are 3 examples of the code for which I want to log dropped rows:

```
df_jobs_by_user = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['owner', 'job_number'], keep='first')
df.drop(df.index[indexes], inplace=True)
df = df.drop(df[df.submission_time.dt.strftime('%Y') != '2018'].index)
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34297763/9677043) solution to a different `.drop` case that uses `pd.isnull` to recode a `pd.dropna` statement and so allows a log to be generated prior to actually dropping the rows:

`df.dropna(subset=['col2', 'col3']).equals(df.loc[~pd.isnull(df[['col2', 'col3']]).any(axis=1)])`

But in trying to adapt it to `pd.drop_duplicates`, I find there is no `pd.isduplicate` parallel to `pd.isnull`, so this may not be the best way to achieve the results I need.

---

**EDIT**

I rewrote my question here to be more precise about the result I want.

I start with a df that has one dupe row:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([['whatever', 'dupe row', 'x'], ['idx 1', 'uniq row', np.nan], ['sth diff', 'dupe row', 'x']], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
print(df)

# Output:
       col1      col2 col3
0  whatever  dupe row    x
1     idx 1  uniq row  NaN
2  sth diff  dupe row    x
```

I then implement the solution from jjp:

```
df_droplog = pd.DataFrame()
mask = df.duplicated(subset=['col2', 'col3'], keep='first')
df_keep = df.loc[~mask]
df_droplog = df.append(df.loc[mask])
```

I print the results:

```
print(df_keep)
# Output:
       col1      col2 col3
0  whatever  dupe row    x
1     idx 1  uniq row  NaN
```

`df_keep` is what I expect and want.

```
print(df_droplog)
# Output:
       col1      col2 col3
0  whatever  dupe row    x
1     idx 1  uniq row  NaN
2  sth diff  dupe row    x
2  sth diff  dupe row    x
```

`df_droplog` is not what I want. It includes the rows from index 0 and index 1 which were *not* dropped and which I therefore do not want in my drop log. It also includes the row from index 2 twice. I want it only once.

What I want:

```
print(df_droplog)
# Output:
       col1      col2 col3
2  sth diff  dupe row    x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only want the duplicated rows in df_droplog, just append only those to an empty dataframe. What you were doing was appending them to the original dataframe `df`. Try this,

```
df_droplog = pd.DataFrame()
mask = df.duplicated(subset=['col2', 'col3'], keep='first')
df_keep = df.loc[~mask]
df_droplog = df_droplog.append(df.loc[mask])
```

Comment: Thank you for spotting that and letting me know! Yes, now I see and now it works. Much thanks also for not just telling me "you're updating the wrong df" but also taking the time to post the correct code. Very helpful as I had been thinking the issue was somewhere else.

Comment: @jpp The issue was with `df.append`. Check out what he wants. According to that, the solution is `df_droplog.append`.

Comment: @jpp I didn't think it to be a typo. Honestly.

Comment: Reposting someone else's answer with a one word fix as a separate post is definitely going to net you points but is not going to make you many friends.

Comment: @coldspeed Absolutely true and I always avoid doing it too. This time, @jpp's explanation was about the function `duplicated` while the solution was wrong. I didn't think deeply and just answered it. if removing my post helps, I am willing to go ahead and do it.

Answer (score 5):

There is a parallel: [`pd.DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) returns a Boolean series. You can use it as follows:

```
df_droplog = pd.DataFrame()

mask = df.duplicated(subset=['owner', 'job_number'], keep='first')
df_jobs_by_user = df.loc[~mask]

df_droplog = df_droplog.append(df.loc[mask])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting funny results. I started w/ a 3-row df, 2 dupes. `df_jobs_by_user` is good, but `df_droplog` has 4 rows, not 1. Expected?
**0** import pd, np
**1** `df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b', np.nan], ['c', 'd', 'a'], ['a', 'b', np.nan]], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])` 
**2** `df_droplog = pd.DataFrame()`
**3** `mask = df.duplicated(subset=['col2', 'col3'], keep='first')`
**4** `df_jobs_by_user = df.loc[~mask]`
**5** `df_droplog = df.append(df.loc[mask])`
**6** `df_droplog`
```
  col1 col2 col3
0    a    b  NaN
1    c    d    a
2    a    b  NaN
2    a    b  NaN```

Comment: I edited my original question to show the result I want.