# How to find which columns contain any NaN value in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

Given a pandas dataframe containing possible NaN values scattered here and there:

**Question:** How do I determine which columns contain NaN values? In particular, can I get a list of the column names containing NaNs?

Comment: `df.isna().any()[lambda x: x]` works for me

Answer (score 423, accepted):

**UPDATE:** using Pandas 0.22.0

Newer Pandas versions have new methods ['DataFrame.isna()'](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and ['DataFrame.notna()'](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html)

```
In [71]: df
Out[71]:
     a    b  c
0  NaN  7.0  0
1  0.0  NaN  4
2  2.0  NaN  4
3  1.0  7.0  0
4  1.0  3.0  9
5  7.0  4.0  9
6  2.0  6.0  9
7  9.0  6.0  4
8  3.0  0.0  9
9  9.0  0.0  1

In [72]: df.isna().any()
Out[72]:
a     True
b     True
c    False
dtype: bool
```

as list of columns:

```
In [74]: df.columns[df.isna().any()].tolist()
Out[74]: ['a', 'b']
```

to select those columns (containing at least one `NaN` value):

```
In [73]: df.loc[:, df.isna().any()]
Out[73]:
     a    b
0  NaN  7.0
1  0.0  NaN
2  2.0  NaN
3  1.0  7.0
4  1.0  3.0
5  7.0  4.0
6  2.0  6.0
7  9.0  6.0
8  3.0  0.0
9  9.0  0.0
```

---

**OLD answer:**

Try to use [isnull()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html):

```
In [97]: df
Out[97]:
     a    b  c
0  NaN  7.0  0
1  0.0  NaN  4
2  2.0  NaN  4
3  1.0  7.0  0
4  1.0  3.0  9
5  7.0  4.0  9
6  2.0  6.0  9
7  9.0  6.0  4
8  3.0  0.0  9
9  9.0  0.0  1

In [98]: pd.isnull(df).sum() > 0
Out[98]:
a     True
b     True
c    False
dtype: bool
```

or as @root proposed clearer version:

```
In [5]: df.isnull().any()
Out[5]:
a     True
b     True
c    False
dtype: bool

In [7]: df.columns[df.isnull().any()].tolist()
Out[7]: ['a', 'b']
```

to select a subset - all columns containing at least one `NaN` value:

```
In [31]: df.loc[:, df.isnull().any()]
Out[31]:
     a    b
0  NaN  7.0
1  0.0  NaN
2  2.0  NaN
3  1.0  7.0
4  1.0  3.0
5  7.0  4.0
6  2.0  6.0
7  9.0  6.0
8  3.0  0.0
9  9.0  0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am looking to get a list of the column names (I updated my question accordingly), do you know how?

Comment: Do you know a good a way to select all columns with a specific value instead of null values?

Comment: Nevermind! Simply replace .isnull() with .isin(['xxx']) to search for values instead of nulls: `df.columns[df.isin['xxx'].any()].tolist()`

Comment: @gregorio099, i'd do it this way: `df.columns[df.eq(search_for_value).any()].tolist()`

Comment: Nice answer, already upvoted. Idea - can you add new functions `isna`, `notna`  ?

Comment: How might one go about saving the results of df.columns[df.isna().any()].tolist() to a new column in df by row? I tried df['new_col']=df.columns[df.isna().any()].tolist() but got an error.

Comment: Nice!  BUT HOW TO DO IT FOR EVERY ROW?   Creating additional column with string of column names with nan in this row?

Comment: @AntonMakarov, I think you may want to open a new question with a small reproducible example ;)

Answer (score 45):

You can use `df.isnull().sum()`. It shows all columns and the total NaNs of each feature.

Comment: Do you have a quick approach for using and setting conditions based on this method.? For example, if col4 and col5 and col6 is null: df=df[["col1","col2","col3"]]

Answer (score 27):

I had a problem where I had to many columns to visually inspect on the screen so a shortlist comp that filters and returns the offending columns is

```
nan_cols = [i for i in df.columns if df[i].isnull().any()]
```

if that's helpful to anyone

Adding to that if you want to filter out columns having more nan values than a threshold, say 85% then use

`nan_cols85 = [i for i in df.columns if df[i].isnull().sum() > 0.85*len(data)]`

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me,

**1. For getting Columns having at least 1 null value. (column names)**

```
data.columns[data.isnull().any()]
```

**2. For getting Columns with count, with having at least 1 null value.**

```
data[data.columns[data.isnull().any()]].isnull().sum()
```

**[Optional]**
**3. For getting percentage of the null count.**

```
data[data.columns[data.isnull().any()]].isnull().sum() * 100 / data.shape[0]
```

Answer (score 9):

```
df.columns[df.isnull().any()].tolist()
```

it will return name of columns that contains null rows

Answer (score 8):

I know this is a very well-answered question but I wanted to add a slight adjustment. This answer only returns columns containing nulls, and also still shows the count of the nulls.

#### As 1-liner:

```
pd.isnull(df).sum()[pd.isnull(df).sum() > 0]
```

#### Description

1. Count nulls in each column

```
null_count_ser = pd.isnull(df).sum()
```

2. True|False series describing if that column had nulls

```
is_null_ser = null_count_ser > 0
```

3. Use the T|F series to filter out those without

```
null_count_ser[is_null_ser]
```

#### Example Output

```
name          5
phone         187
age           644
```

Answer (score 6):

In datasets having large number of columns its even better to see how many columns contain null values and how many don't.

```
print("No. of columns containing null values")
print(len(df.columns[df.isna().any()]))

print("No. of columns not containing null values")
print(len(df.columns[df.notna().all()]))

print("Total no. of columns in the dataframe")
print(len(df.columns))
```

For example in my dataframe it contained 82 columns, of which 19 contained at least one null value.

Further you can also **automatically remove cols and rows** depending on which has more null values
Here is the code which does this intelligently:

```
df = df.drop(df.columns[df.isna().sum()>len(df.columns)],axis = 1)
df = df.dropna(axis = 0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Note:** Above code removes all of your null values. If you want null values, process them before.

Answer (score 3):

i use these three lines of code to print out the column names which contain at least one null value:

```
for column in dataframe:
    if dataframe[column].isnull().any():
       print('{0} has {1} null values'.format(column, dataframe[column].isnull().sum()))
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the methods..

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,np.nan], 'b':[np.nan,1,np.nan],'c':[np.nan,2,np.nan], 'd':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})
print(pd.isnull(df).sum())
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud5Fc.png)

Answer (score 2):

Both of these should work:

```
df.isnull().sum()
df.isna().sum()
```

DataFrame methods `isna()` or `isnull()` are completely identical.

**Note**: Empty strings `''` is considered as False (not considered NA)

Answer (score 1):

`df.isna()` return **True** values for NaN, **False** for the rest. So, doing:

`df.isna().any()`

will return True for any column having a NaN, **False** for the rest

Answer (score 0):

To see just the columns containing NaNs and just the rows containing NaNs:

```
isnulldf = df.isnull()
columns_containing_nulls = isnulldf.columns[isnulldf.any()]
rows_containing_nulls = df[isnulldf[columns_containing_nulls].any(axis='columns')].index
only_nulls_df = df[columns_containing_nulls].loc[rows_containing_nulls]
print(only_nulls_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

features_with_na=[features for features in dataframe.columns if dataframe[features].isnull().sum()>0]

for feature in features_with_na:
print(feature, np.round(dataframe[feature].isnull().mean(), 4),  '% missing values')
print(features_with_na)

##### it  will give % of missing value for each column in dataframe

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write it as a one-liner (could be useful if functions need to be called sequentially in a pipeline), then you can do so using either `pipe()` or passing a callable to `loc[]`. `pipe()` can be used to get the columns with NaN values as well.

```py
df.isna().any().pipe(lambda x: x.index[x])

df.isna().any().loc[lambda x: x].index
```

A working example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, pd.NA],
    'b': [10, 20, 30],
    'c': [pd.NA, 'B', 'C']
})


df.isna().any().pipe(lambda x: x.index[x])  # Index(['a', 'c'], dtype='object')
df.isna().any().loc[lambda x: x].index      # Index(['a', 'c'], dtype='object')


df.isna().any().pipe(lambda x: df.loc[:, x])


      a     c
0     1  <NA>
1     2     B
2  <NA>     C
```

---

If you want to opposite, i.e. columns without any NaN, then `notna().all()` could be used instead of `isna().any()`.

```py
df.notna().all().pipe(lambda x: x.index[x])  # Index(['b'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for printing columns alongside their respective null_values:

```
null_cols = [i for i in df.columns if df[i].isnull().any()] 
for i in null_cols:
    print(i,df[i].isnull().sum())
```

Answer (score -2):

The code works if you want to find columns containing NaN values and get a list of the column names.

```py
na_names = df.isnull().any()
list(na_names.where(na_names == True).dropna().index)
```

If you want to find columns whose values are **all** NaNs, you can replace `any` with `all`.