# Subset columns with NaN values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Searched and tried several answers here on SO, but they are all for returning rows with NaN's. I'd like to return only the columns with NaN values. For example the following df. How can I select columns 'A' and 'LG'?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'H': ['a','b', 'c'],
         'A': [np.nan,'d', 'e'],
         'LG':['AR1', 'RO1', np.nan],
         })

print(df)

     A  H   LG
0  NaN  a  AR1
1    d  b  RO1
2    e  c  NaN
```

Comment: possible dupe: [How to find which columns contain any NaN value in Pandas dataframe (python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36226083/how-to-find-which-columns-contain-any-nan-value-in-pandas-dataframe-python)

Comment: in part I believe so. I'm asking for a subset, however that one is returning the column names only

Comment: good point, thanks! I've updated [that post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36226137/5741205)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need first replace strings `NaN` to `np.nan` in sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'H': ['a','b', 'c'],
         'A': [np.nan,'d', 'e'],
         'LG':['AR1', 'RO1', np.nan],
         })
```

Then check by [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) and [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
mask = df.isnull().any()
print (mask)
A      True
H     False
LG     True
dtype: bool
```

Last use boolean indexing with `index`:

```
print (mask.index[mask])
Index(['A', 'LG'], dtype='object')
```

If need columns add `loc`:

```
print (df.loc[:, mask])
     A   LG
0  NaN  AR1
1    d  RO1
2    e  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

This returns all columns containing `NaN`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'H': ['a','b', 'c'],
         'A': [np.nan,'d', 'e'],
         'LG':['AR1', 'RO1', np.nan],
         })

x = pd.isnull(df).any()

print(df[x.index[x]])

     A   LG
0  NaN  AR1
1    d  RO1
2    e  Na
```