# Delete rows in dataframe based on column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to rid myself of all rows with a null value in column C. Here is the code:

```
infile="C:\****"

df=pd.read_csv(infile)    

A   B   C   D
1   1   NaN 3
2   3   7   NaN
4   5   NaN 8
5   NaN 4   9
NaN 1   2   NaN
```

There are two basic methods I have attempted.

method 1:
source: [How to drop rows of Pandas DataFrame whose value in certain columns is NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-of-certain-column-is-nan)

```
df.dropna()
```

The result is an empty dataframe, which makes sense because there is an NaN value in every row.

```
df.dropna(subset=[3])
```

For this method I tried to play around with the subset value using both column index number and column name.  The dataframe is still empty.

method 2:
source: [Deleting DataFrame row in Pandas based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value)

```
df = df[df.C.notnull()]
```

Still results in an empty dataframe!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `df.dropna(subset=['C'])`

Comment: And the second method does not return an empty dataframe. Could it be the case your first attempt emptied the dataframe?

Comment: yep, method 2 should work as well

Comment: I am positive the dataframe is full because I have been printing it on the line directly prior.  @MaxU df.dropna(subset=["C"]) prints a full dataframe, including null values! So frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,np.nan,3],[2,3,7,np.nan],[4,5,np.nan,8],[5,np.nan,4,9],[np.nan,1,2,np.nan]], columns = ['A','B','C','D'])
df = df[df['C'].notnull()]
df
```

Comment: @EdChum He didn't like notnull() up above, so I gave him some variety :)

Comment: It looks to me the OP got an empty dataframe due to the first incorrect operation

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a prove that your `method 2` works properly (at least with pandas 0.18.0):

```
In [100]: df
Out[100]:
     A    B    C    D
0  1.0  1.0  NaN  3.0
1  2.0  3.0  7.0  NaN
2  4.0  5.0  NaN  8.0
3  5.0  NaN  4.0  9.0
4  NaN  1.0  2.0  NaN

In [101]: df.dropna(subset=['C'])
Out[101]:
     A    B    C    D
1  2.0  3.0  7.0  NaN
3  5.0  NaN  4.0  9.0
4  NaN  1.0  2.0  NaN

In [102]: df[df.C.notnull()]
Out[102]:
     A    B    C    D
1  2.0  3.0  7.0  NaN
3  5.0  NaN  4.0  9.0
4  NaN  1.0  2.0  NaN

In [103]: df = df[df.C.notnull()]

In [104]: df
Out[104]:
     A    B    C    D
1  2.0  3.0  7.0  NaN
3  5.0  NaN  4.0  9.0
4  NaN  1.0  2.0  NaN
```

Comment: Ok, so the difference must have to do with my dataset.  Or is it possible my NaN values are not actually recognized as null?  They were generated using pandas.merge.

Comment: @geolish, just print `df.isnull()` - you should see `True` values in the cells containing NaN's