# How to drop the rows having two empty column in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have 3 columns in dataframe A,B,C.I want to remove the rows having null in both B and C column

Comment: A = 1,2,3,4,5 and B = 1,2,null,4,null and C = 1,2,3,4,null
Output : A = 1,2,3,4 and B = 1,2,null,4 and C = 1,2,3,4

Comment: Try: `df = df.dropna(subset=['B','C'], how='all')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Drop row if two columns are NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128856/python-drop-row-if-two-columns-are-nan)