# Remove rows based on a specific columns attribute

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I have a matrix with header's and want to remove all rows based on the column, "Closed Date", having "NaN".

Input:

```
raw_data.ix[~(raw_data['Closed Date'] == "NaN")]
```

Output:

```
Closed Date
NaN
NaN
9/28/2017 19:51     
NaN
```

Why is "NaN" still there?

Comment: try`raw_data.ix[~(raw_data['Closed Date'] == None)]` or `raw_data.ix[~(raw_data['Closed Date'] == np.nan)]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to drop rows of Pandas DataFrame whose value in certain columns is NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-in-certain-columns-is-nan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NaN is not a string. You need to test for `.notnull()`

```
raw_data.ix[~(raw_data['Closed Date'].isnull())]
```

or

```
raw_data.ix[raw_data['Closed Date'].notnull()]
```

Comment: what is the difference with ~ and no ~ @Sebastian ?

Comment: `~` inverts a boolean series. If you have `x=[False, True, False]`. `~x = [True, False, True]`

Answer (score 0):

The `NaN` you are seeing is not a string. It stands for "Not a Number" and is used to represent "Not Available" data in `pandas` / `numpy`.

You can remove all rows where `Closed Date` is `NaN` via [`pd.DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
raw_data = raw_data.dropna(subset=['Closed Date'], axis=1)
```

Comment: `ValueError: No axis named Closed Date for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` I get this error