# Drop rows with masked elements in astropy Table

Tags: python, astropy

Consider an `astropy` [Table() object](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/index.html#astropy-table).

```
from astropy.io import ascii

weather_data = """
  day,precip,type
  ,1.5,rain
  Tues, 9.,
  Wed,1.1,snow
  ed,,aaa
  Wd,1.1,snow
  """

dat = ascii.read(weather_data)
print(dat)

day  precip type
---- ------ ----
  --    1.5 rain
Tues    9.0   --
 Wed    1.1 snow
  ed     --  aaa
  Wd    1.1 snow
```

I need to drop all rows that contain at least one masked element. The final table should then look like:

```
day  precip type
---- ------ ----
 Wed    1.1 snow
  Wd    1.1 snow
```

This seems like a simple task, but I could not find a way t do it in the [docs](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/ascii/read.html).

**Add**

I know that I could use `.to_pandas()` to convert the table to a `pandas` object and then use something like [`.dropna()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-in-certain-columns-is-nan?rq=1), but this forces me to have `pandas` installed which I don't want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a generalized way

```
import operator
# if python3: from functools import reduce
dat[reduce(operator.and_, [~dat[col].mask for col in dat.columns])]

day   precip type
str4 float64 str4
---- ------- ----
 Wed     1.1 snow
  Wd     1.1 snow
```

---

What this process does is simply a generalized way of doing

```
dat[(~dat['day'].mask) & (~dat['precip'].mask) & (~dat['type'].mask)]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. It shouldn't be necessary to do this though, I'll open an issue about this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
dat.remove_rows(np.where([c.data for c in dat.mask.itercols()])[-1])
```

But I agree with you that this filtering of invalid values should be supported by a masked table.

Comment: This is also a great answer. The difference is that this one changes the table in place.