# Advanced MultiIndex sorting and indexing

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, indexing

I have a data with >100k rows and I need to efficiently regroup it from the left DataFrame to the multiindexed right one which indices are sorted by the sum of values in the 3rd column and inside each index 2nd column values are sorted by values in the 3rd column. All sortings are descending.

I have no idea how to do it correctly and already spent whole day figuring it out.

```
 a   b  c           a sum b  c  %
foo one 1          foo 5 one 3 3/5
foo two 2                two 2 2/5
bar one 1    =>    baz 4 two 3 3/4
baz one 1                one 1 1/4
baz two 3          bar 3 six 2 2/3
foo one 2                one 1 1/3
bar six 2
```

**UPDATE**:
The code given by @**jezrael** works really good but it outputs in this way:

```
                  %
a   sum b   c      
foo 5   one 3  0.60
        two 2  0.40
        six NaN NaN
baz 4   two 3  0.75
        one 1  0.25
        six NaN NaN
bar 1   one 1  1.00
        two NaN NaN
        six NaN NaN
```

Is it possible to get rid of these strings with NaN?

**UPDATE #2:**
I've found the problem which gives NaNs problem. This was caused by *'category'* data type. How it affects the behavior of the code I don't know. Just pointing out the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe need:

```
#aggregate sum by a, b columns
df = df.groupby(['a','b'], as_index=False)['c'].sum()
print (df)
     a    b  c
0  bar  one  1
1  baz  one  1
2  baz  two  3
3  foo  one  3
4  foo  two  2

#create new column by position with transform sum per a column
df.insert(1, 'sum', df.groupby('a')['c'].transform('sum'))
#division of columns
df['%'] = df['c'].div(df['sum'])
print (df)
     a  sum    b  c     %
0  bar    1  one  1  1.00
1  baz    4  one  1  0.25
2  baz    4  two  3  0.75
3  foo    5  one  3  0.60
4  foo    5  two  2  0.40

#sorting by multiple columns and create MultiIndex  
df = df.sort_values(['sum','c'], ascending=False).set_index(['a','sum','b', 'c'])
print (df)
                  %
a   sum b   c      
foo 5   one 3  0.60
        two 2  0.40
baz 4   two 3  0.75
        one 1  0.25
bar 1   one 1  1.00
```

Comment: Thank you for such a fast reply. It seems to be working. Now I need to understand what's going on under the hood. Can you recommend any sources to read about such things? It seems like googling and reading docs didn't work well for me. Thank you again.

Comment: @yol - Sure, in pandas docs are very nice [tutorials](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html), I like especially [modern pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html#modern-pandas)

Comment: The only problem I've found is that column 'b' has all possible occurrences of values (not only the ones with representation in 'c' column).

Comment: @yol - Can you explain more? Maybe you can change data with expected output for better explanation.

Comment: @yol - There is bad formating of comments, can you edite question?

Comment: @yol - Not sure, if understand each other, I think [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51169517/edit) question.

Comment: @yol - Interesting, what is your pandas version? I cannot simulate your problem. I add dataframes to answer, do you get same ouptut with data sample?

Comment: Yes I understood you, I edited the question. I'm sorry, it feels like I'm actually trying to ask you to solve my task. I really appreciate your help.
Pandas v.0.23

Comment: I tried to run your code right the way you edited your post and it seems like the problem occurs right after the first line of code.

Comment: Waht is `print (df.to_dict())` ?

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: I recreated exampled DataFrame and it works just fine while my real data still gives me these NaN. This means that your code works perfectly and the problem is with my data. Now I have to understand what it is.

P.S. Output for working df: {'%': {('foo', 5, 'one', 3): 0.6, ...}}
Output for real data is really big but seems to have the same pattern except for having these NaNs.
P.P.S. Pandas v.0.23 as I mentioned before

Comment: I've found the problem. If you're interested you can read the update#2 in my question.

Comment: You can use `df = df.dropna(how='all')`, check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13434501)

Comment: Thank you very much for support :)

Comment: @yol - It is expected, check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#operations). Just convert columns to `string` for prevent it. `cols = ['a','b']` and then `df[cols] = df[cols].astype(str)`

Comment: Yes, I already did that. Actually I cancelled convertion to `category` which I was implementing to optimize memory usage.