# Pandas dropna on specific rows

Tags: python, pandas

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ticker':['x','x','y','z','z'],
                   'bid':[1,2,np.nan,2,np.nan]})
```

Using pandas `.dropna()` is there anyway to drop the rows from a specified index range or subset of the data? For example in the DataFrame above, if I want to only drop rows in the index for where ticker equals `'z'`. This would hopefully return:

```
ticker bid
x       1
x       2
y       np.nan
z       2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to drop rows of Pandas DataFrame whose value in a certain column is NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-in-a-certain-column-is-nan)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) **with [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html)** and [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df.mask(df.eq('z')).dropna(how='all').fillna({'ticker':'z'})
```

Output:

```
 ticker  bid
0      x  1.0
1      x  2.0
2      y  NaN
3      z  2.0
```

or

```
df.mask(df.eq('z')).dropna(how='all').mask(df.eq('z'),'z')
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to just check the two conditions separately:

```
In [13]: df[(df['bid'].notnull()) | (df['ticker'] != 'z')]
Out[13]:
```

---

```
  ticker  bid
0      x  1.0
1      x  2.0
2      y  NaN
3      z  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
df.loc[df.ticker == "z"] = df.loc[df.ticker == "z"].dropna()
df.dropna(subset=["ticker"])
```

Not sure if this is better for when I have more columns and need to specify if they have 2 missing nan's (using the `.dropna(thresh=2)` in the first drop)