# Select rows of a dataframe where at least one column is NaN

Tags: python, pandas

we all know the famous question: [How to drop rows of Pandas DataFrame whose value in a certain column is NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-in-a-certain-column-is-nan)

But how can I select the rows in a pandas dataframe `df`, where at least one column is NaN. So that:

```
df
   columnA columnB
0   NaN        1
1   1          2
2   NaN       NaN
3   1         NaN
```

will lead to:

```
df
   columnA columnB
0   NaN        1
2   NaN       NaN
3   1         NaN
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `isnull` with `any`

```
df[df.isnull().any(1)]
Out[122]: 
   columnA  columnB
0      NaN      1.0
2      NaN      NaN
3      1.0      NaN
```

Comment: `isnull()` or `isna()`?

Comment: @PV8 both of them work