# Get data from column that are not nan values

Tags: python, pandas

I have excel file with data list like:

```
column 1 column 2 column 3
 1          2        2
            3        5
                     6
```

I want to have a list with arrays for each column.

```
    sampling = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheetname=0, index_row=1)
    print(sampling)
    array = []
    for i in range(0,3):
        array2 = sampling['column '+ str(i+1)].tolist()
        array.append(array2)

    print(array)        

   column 1  column 2  column 3
0       1.0       2.0         2
1       NaN       3.0         5
2       NaN       NaN         6
[[1.0, nan, nan], [2.0, 3.0, nan], [2, 5, 6]]
```

How to get only non Nan values?
I want to have such result

```
[[1.0], [2.0, 3.0], [2, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create lists with missing values and then remove them:

```
L = [x.dropna().tolist() for _, x in df.items()]
print (L)
[[1.0], [2.0, 3.0], [2, 5, 6]]
```

Or:

```
L = [[y for y in x if pd.notna(y)] for _, x in df.items()]
print (L)
[[1.0], [2.0, 3.0], [2, 5, 6]]
```

If want use your solution only add [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) for remove missing values:

```
array = []
for i in range(0,3):
    array2 = sampling['column '+ str(i+1)].dropna().tolist()
    array.append(array2)

print(array)        
[[1.0], [2.0, 3.0], [2, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

**pandas.DataFrame.dropna**

(Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

This will drop NaN values from a pandas DataTable object.

Edit: Alternatively, you can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-in-a-certain-column-is-nan?rq=1) which shows a different method.

Comment: As far as I understand it is not what I wanted. I want to get all non Nan values so this mean something like this ```[[1.0], [2.0, 3.0], [2, 5, 6]]``` and using dropna I'll lose columns with data.

Comment: My bad, I didn't fully understand what you were looking for. It looks like @jezrael's answer does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, add one line:

`filtered_sampling = sampling[sampling[['column '+ str(i+1)]].notnull().all(1)]`

into your loop. Then use `filtered_sampling`.

To conclude:

```
array = []
for i in range(0,3):

    filtered_sampling = sampling[sampling[['column '+ str(i+1)]].notnull().all(1)]
    array2 = filtered_sampling['column '+ str(i+1)].tolist()
    array.append(array2)

print(array)
```