# Pandas dropna with multilevel column index

Tags: python, pandas

So I have got this Pandas DataFrame with multilevel index for the columns:

```
   group1    group2    group3
   1    2    1    2    1    2
0  ...  ...  NaN  ...  ...  ...
1  NaN  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
2  ...  ...  ...  ...  NaN  ...
```

Now i want to drop the rows where the columns `group2` and `group3` have NaN values. Which equates to rows 0 and 2 in this instance.

According to my understanding of the documentation this should work:

```
df.dropna(axis = 'rows', subset = ['group2', 'group3'])
```

But it does not. Instead I get the error:

```
KeyError: ['group2', 'group3']
```

Could someone please point out to me how to properly specify the subset?

Kind regards,
Rasmus

---

Update

So it seems like .dropna() cannot work with mulitlevel column indexes. In the end I went with the less elegant, but workable method suggested, slightly rewritten:

```
mask_nan = df[['group2', 'group3']].isna().any(axis = 'columns')
df[~mask_nan]    # ~ to negate / flip the boolean values
```

Comment: Well, `df.dropna(subset = ['column_name'])` should do the job. Can you try dropping one at a time?

Comment: No luck, just a shorter `KeyError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like we can not pass the index `level` in `dropna` , so we could do

```
df.loc[:,['group2', 'group3']].isna().any(1)
```

Then

```
df=df[df.loc[:,['group2', 'group3']].isna().any(1)]
```

Comment: I don't think you need `loc` you can just use `df[['group2', 'group3']]`

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a similiar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-in-a-certain-column-is-nan) to yours.

```
import numpy as np

df = df[np.isfinite(df['group2', 'group3'])]
```

Only the rows where the values are finite are taken into account here.

Comment: Since I pass a total of four columns (two column groups of two a piece) would I not get a boolean array? I would need a Pandas Series, to pass back as an index mask.

Answer (score 1):

Start from detail. When you run:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[:, idx['group2':'group3']]
```

You will get columns for *group2* and *group3*:

```
  group2     group3    
       1   2      1   2
0    NaN   3    4.0   5
1    8.0   9   10.0  11
2   14.0  15    NaN  17
```

Now a more compicated expession:

```
df.loc[:, idx['group2':'group3']].notnull().all(axis=1)
```

will display a *boolean Series* with *True* where all columns are not null:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

So the code that you need is to use the above code in *boolean indexing*:

```
df[df.loc[:, idx['group2':'group3']].notnull().all(axis=1)]
```

(+ `idx = pd.IndexSlice` before).