# How to select rows from a dataframe which all column values are null in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I Have dataframe like below.

```
df.head(10)
    ORD  A   B   C    D
    198  23  45  NaN  12
    138  25  NaN NaN  62
    469  NaN NaN NaN  NaN
    625  52  36  49   35
    457  NaN NaN NaN  82
    427  NaN NaN NaN  NaN
    626  52  32  39   45
```

I want remove  rows from the dataframe which are having NaN  values in  column A,B,C,D at the same time.

**Expected  Output**

```
    ORD  A   B   C    D
    198  23  45  NaN  12
    138  25  NaN NaN  62
    625  52  36  49   35
    457  NaN NaN NaN  82
    626  52  32  39   45
```

How can this be done in pandas?

Comment: Just check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-in-a-certain-column-is-nan

Comment: @anky_91, Could  you as a answer, it will helpful for others

Comment: @pankaj it is a dupe :) `df.dropna(subset=['A','B','C','D'], how='all')`