# How do i remove nan values from dataframe in Python. dropna() does not seem to be working for me

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nan

How do i remove nan values from dataframe in Python? I already tried with `dropna()`, but that did not work for me. Also is NaN diffferent from nan. I am using Pandas.

While printing the data frame it does not print as NaN but instead as nan.

```
1                  2.11358      0.649067060588935
2                  nan          0.6094130485307419
3                  2.10066      0.3653980276694516
4                  2.10545                     nan
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to drop rows of Pandas DataFrame whose value in a certain column is NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-in-a-certain-column-is-nan)

Answer (score 1):

You can change `nan` values with `NaN` using `replace()` and then use `dropna()`.

```
import numpy as np

df = df.replace('nan', np.nan)
df = df.dropna()
```

Update:

Original dataframe:

```
1  2.11358   0.649067060588935
2      nan  0.6094130485307419
3  2.10066  0.3653980276694516
4  2.10545                 nan
```

Applied `df.replace('nan', np.nan)`:

```
1  2.11358   0.649067060588935
2      NaN  0.6094130485307419
3  2.10066  0.3653980276694516
4  2.10545                 NaN
```

Applied `df.dropna()`:

```
1  2.11358   0.649067060588935
3  2.10066  0.3653980276694516
```

Comment: This is not working:(  I just tried this too. Still the data frame contains nan values

Comment: Are you sure you are not missing something? I just tried with your dataset and it worked well. I also updated the answer you can check step by step.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input. I will check it again. i don't think I missed any of the step