# Removing float values from lists within a Pandas Column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with a column where each value is a list of elements. A combination of string and nan values (Which is indicating as dtype: float). Here are the first two elements:

```
1    [nan, JavaScript, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan...

2    [Java, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, SQL, nan, nan,...
```

I am trying to remove the nan values from each list within the column, so that only the strings remain within each list.

Does anyone have any idea of how I could drop these float values while retaining the string values in an efficient manner?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to drop rows of Pandas DataFrame whose value in a certain column is NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-in-a-certain-column-is-nan)

Comment: Drop or replace? You cannot just drop things - imagine dropping column 1, you'd also drop `Java`.

Comment: I don't want to drop the rows specifically, I just want to remove the 'nan' values from each list

Comment: Hey anky, I was referring to mo2ph3u5's comments about dropping columns. I finally got time this morning to try out your solutions. Thank you so much! While the first solution threw some errors, the second solution worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a list comprehension with `pd.notnull()`

```
df['cleaned_col_name'] = [[e for e in i if pd.notnull(e)] for i in df['col_name']]
```

Or create a dataframe from the column and `stack()` then aggregate back as list

```
df['cleaned_col_name'] = pd.DataFrame(df['col_name'].tolist()).stack()
                                           .groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

Or with explode:

```
df['col_name'].explode().dropna().groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

Replace `col_name` and `cleaned_col_name` from the code with the existing column name and desired column name.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this;

```
df['your_column'] = df['your_column'].map(lambda x: [w for w in x if not isinstance(w, numpy.NaN)])
```

Result;

```
1    [JavaScript, ...

2    [Java, SQL, ...
```

Comment: I recieve: TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types when attempting this