# I used dropna() on Python but it didn't deleted any rows

Tags: python, pandas, nan, drop

My DataFrame has two columns, both of which have NaN values. I need to delete the rows with NaN just on the column user_email.

However, I used `df['user_email'] = df['user_email'].dropna()` but it returned the exact same DataFrame, with all the NaN values on the second column intact.

How can I delete the rows with NaN on the second column?
[image: Here's my DF:]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62444845/4909087

Answer (score 0):

You could use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). This allows you to select rows based on a conditional statement (e.g., `df.user_email.notna()`)

```
df = df[df.user_email.notna()]
```

Comment: Code only answers can generally be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work. Without that explanation it looks like a low quality answer when it hits the review queues.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated my answer to include an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `subset` keyword argument.

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['user_email'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need [inplace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)=True:

```
df.dropna(subset=['user_email'], inplace=True)
```