# How to remove rows that contains only NaN values in all columns of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like below.

**Input**

```
df

A     B     C
1     2     1
NaN   4     2
3     NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN
4     2     NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN
```

**Output**

```
  A     B     C
  1     2     1
  NaN   4     2
  3     NaN   NaN
  4     2     NaN
```

How can this be done in python

Answer (score 5):

```py
df.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'all')
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use:

```
df.dropna(how='all')
```

you can look into this thread also: [How to drop rows of Pandas DataFrame whose value in a certain column is NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-in-a-certain-column-is-nan)

Answer (score -1):

You can select the `df` which is not `NaN` rather than dropping it:

```
df = df[~((df['A'].isna()) & (df['B'].isna()) & (df['C'].isna()))]
```

This gives a bit more capability if you want to filter your `df` by certain values of each column.

```
A     B     C
1     2     1
NaN   4     2
3     NaN   NaN
4     2     NaN
```

You can use `df.dropna??` to get the information about the `dropna` functionality.