# How drop rows with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two rows like that:

[image]

How can I drop it?

I try:

```
to_excl = df.loc[df['tabela_segproposta.RENOVAR'].isnull()]
df = df[df['tabela_segproposta.RENOVAR'].isin(to_excl).index]
df
```

but nothings happen

Comment: See [.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) method. You can use: `df.dropna(subset=['tabela_segproposta.RENOVAR'])`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to drop rows of Pandas DataFrame whose value in a certain column is NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-in-a-certain-column-is-nan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
new_df = df[~df['tabela_segproposta.RENOVAR'].isnull()]
```

Comment: worked perfectly! Thank you! But why did you use ~ ?

Comment: Simply put, you can think of '~' meaning NOT (source: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp)

Comment: Can i remove columns too? Tried but did'nt work

Comment: It doesn't work with columns. To drop columns you can do ```df.drop(['col1','col2',...'colN'],axis=1,inplace=True```