# ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64'). While fitting in model

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('titanic.csv')
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
df['male']=df['Sex']=='male'
X= df[['Pclass','male','Age','SibSp','Parch','Fare']].values
y= df['Survived'].values
model=LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X,y)
```

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

Please Help me to remove this error

Comment: There are `NaN` values in the titanic dataset

Comment: Yes there are nan values

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13413590/11573842

Comment: Thanks I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's the same, but in my case that error was due to big numbers, in particular I found those with scientific notation, such as 3.63E+08, 1.25E+09...
The solution is to replace those numbers with something smaller: you can either simply replace them with x / 1000 or, the best solution, use a function to scale or normalise the data. After that, you can train your model