# combine two rows of dataframe with different index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have a dataframe which looks like this:

[image]

The wanted result is:

[image]

What should I do with pandas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to drop rows of Pandas DataFrame whose value in a certain column is NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-in-a-certain-column-is-nan)

Comment: `df.ffill().dropna(subset=['age'])`

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df=df.dropna(subset=['age']).fillna({'champions':1})
```

or, if you want to fill the values from the previous rows, use [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html):

```
df=df.dropna(subset=['age']).ffill()
```

Comment: You're right, I had not seen the NaN in the second column! I'll fix the answer. Thanks!