# Pandas drop multiple lines instead the ones indicated by the index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Considering a dataframe with insect species, specified in column 'class', I would like to drop entries that have exceeded a certain threshold in order to balance against the ones that does not have many.

```
    df_counts = df['class'].value_counts()
    class_balance = df_counts.where(df_counts > threshold).notnull()

    for idx, item in class_balance.iteritems():
        if item:
            if df_counts[idx] > threshold:
                n = int(df_counts[idx] - threshold)

                df_aux = df.drop(df[df['class'] == idx].sample(n=n).index)
                df_counts_b = df_aux['class'].value_counts()
```

so, I have iterate only over the classes that have exceeded this limit: `df_counts.where(df_counts > threshold).notnull()`, and I would like to update my dataframe, droping the exceeded number of rows: `n`, randomly: `sample(n=n)`.

But seems it does not work in this way, like recommeded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-in-a-certain-column-is-nan). Note the difference between `df_counts` before the drop, and after first iteration:

[image: Before Droping entries]
[image: After first iteration]

Seems the `index` has been messed up. Other class have been deleted. It should be simple to delete rows conditionally, but it just behaves strange. Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up with a simple solution to that behavior, which there was nothing about the drop itself, but a bad structure of indexes. The dataframe was built of multiple CSVs, which has been loaded such as:

```
frames = []
for csv in csv_list:
     df = pd.read_csv(csv)
     frames.append(df)
df_main = pd.concat(frames)
```

the problem, then, was the lack of `ignore_index` in `concat()` procedure:

```
df_main = pd.concat(frames, ignore_index=True)
```

then, it worked fine!