# How to trim columns with NaN while concatenating two series

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am doing so:

```
pandas.concat([
  yfinance.download('btc-usd',interval="1d")["Close"],
  yfinance.download('aapl',interval="1d")["Close"]
],axis=1)
```

And this gives me a dataframe with NaN values, like this:

```
             Close         Close
Date
1980-12-12    0.128348           NaN
1980-12-12    0.128348           NaN
1980-12-16    0.112723           NaN
1980-12-17    0.115513           NaN
1980-12-18    0.118862           NaN
...                ...           ...
2021-12-27  180.330002  50640.417969
2021-12-28  179.289993  47588.855469
2021-12-29  179.380005  46444.710938
2021-12-30  178.199997  47178.125000
2021-12-31         NaN  47804.882812
```

I need to remove all rows which contain NaN value.

Comment: You may want to read the docs on [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

Answer (score -1):

There are many posts answering questions around that topic so this might be a duplicate. For instance [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-in-a-certain-column-is-nan) answers a very similar question.
First, you need to assign the result of the `concat()` call to a variable, say df. Then, you can simply use `dropna()`. Make sure to set the parameter `inplace` to `False` or to reassign the result to a variable so that you can keep track of the rows you're interested in.

```
df = pandas.concat([
  yfinance.download('btc-usd',interval="1d")["Close"],
  yfinance.download('aapl',interval="1d")["Close"]
],axis=1)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df
    Close         Close
Date
2021-12-27  180.330002  50640.417969
2021-12-28  179.289993  47588.855469
2021-12-29  179.380005  46444.710938
2021-12-30  178.199997  47178.125000
```

Comment: Not sure why and who downgraded my answer. If there were at least some feedback about how to improve my answer I would amend it.

Answer (score -2):

If you data is stored in `df`, `df.dropna(axis="index")` will drop rows that have any NaNs in them.