# i want delete a row of #NaN from data frame do i could do a sum and average

Tags: python

the first row of the data i've calculated in #NaN and i can't calculated parameters such as average and sum

```
import pandas as pd
#Read File:
directory = r'/Users/hosseinfatemi/Desktop/MBA Course/4th Semester/1.Quatitative/Economics/1.Project/1.Data'
Read_FDX = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(directory, 'FDX.xlsx'))
#Calculate Returns:
Read_FDX['%Returns'] = Read_FDX['Close'].pct_change().mul(100).round(2) #Average of Returns:
statistics.mean(Read_FDX['%Returns'])
```

[Calculated Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW9Yh.png)

[average](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02gbu.png)

i dont know what to do i tried dropping the row with:
`Read_FDX.drop(index=[0])`

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-in-a-certain-column-is-nan

Comment: `Read_FDX  = Read_FDX.dropna()`, can you try this?

Comment: pandas has it's own [sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) and [mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) functions that ignore NaNs by default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to drop rows of Pandas DataFrame whose value in a certain column is NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-in-a-certain-column-is-nan)