# Remove NaN values from AnnData object

Tags: python, nan

I have an AnnData object that has two columns: one with barcodes and another with cell types, like this:

**barcodes**            **cell_type**

AAACGAACAGGATGTG-1  anterior pharynx

AAACGAAGTTAGGAGC-1  epithelium, ductal cells

AAACGAAGTTAGGAGC-1      NaN

In order to filter out cell types that I do not want, I am using the following command:

```
adata = adata[adata.obs['cell_type'] != 'leukocytes']
```

However, I want to get rid of the NaN values as well.

I have tried the following options, which have not worked

```
adata = adata[adata.obs['cell_type'] != 'NaN']


adata = adata[adata.obs['cell_type'] != np.nan]
```

I then used:

```
scATAC_adata_raw.obs.dropna(how="any")
```

which did the filtering but did not save it in the AnnData object.

Could you help me out filtering the NaN values out of the AnnData object? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Progman I am using python

Answer (score 0):

How about [nan_to_num()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html)?

This function replaces Not a Number to 0

If you only wanna drop NaN you might use a [dropna()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-drop-rows-with-nan-values-in-pandas-dataframe/)

Comment: My goal is to drop the NaN, so I used the second option that you suggested. The issue is that when I use it with this command "scATAC_adata.obs.dropna(how="any")" and then I check the AnnData object with "scATAC_adata", the NaN filtering was not saved and the object has the exact same obs and vars as before the filtering.

Comment: When I deal with machine learning or deep learning dataframe, I never delete the column that which is a NaN, I replace them with 0. Everyone does this in the most professional curses, because deleting a value from the data frame can make a problem in your model.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-in-a-certain-column-is-nan/13413845#13413845), it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to distinguish NaN from other values is that NaN!=NaN is true (at least in Python). This is also why `adata.obs['cell_type'] != np.nan` can only ever be true, nothing is equal to NaN. So you can always get a mask of whether something is NaN by testing this:

```
adata = adata[adata.obs['cell_type'] == adata.obs['cell_type']]
```

This will sort out all NaN values. As somebody else suggested, you could also use the pandas functionality here:

```
adata = adata[adata.obs['cell_type'].notna()]
```