# How do I derive the surnames of everyone whose first names have a condition in a pandas data frame?

Tags: pandas, split, conditional-statements, series, names

Using pandas, I want to derive a last name column for a set of first names that are 4 or more characters long.

I have tried these:

```
data = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")
#split the EmployeeName into firstname and lastname
flname = data['EmployeeName'].str.split(expand=True)

#add first name column to data frame
data['FirstName'] = flname[0]

#apply condition on first name
dfname = data['FirstName'].apply(lambda x:x if len(x) \> 4 else None)
dfname = dfname.dropna()

#add last name and new first name columns to data frame
data['LastName'] = flname[0]
data['NewFirstName'] = dfname

#This is the wrong bit that throws an error
derived_name = data.apply(lambda x:x if data\['FirstName'\] in data\['NewFirstName'\] else None)
derived_name.dropna()
```

#TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'

#Are there shorter ways of writing these code lines with pandas?

Comment: Please add an example of your data (csv)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this with answer to question [1387](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-in-a-certain-column-is-nan?rq=2).

```
df = data[data['NewFirstName'].notna()]
df['LastName']
```

Thanks all. But are there shorter ways to answer the question?

Comment: Do not post redundant (line 2) code that might mislead others.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the data

```
data[['Firstname', 'Lastname']] = data['EmployeeName].str.split(expand=True)
```

After splitting the name columns, you should use masking as it makes this very easy.

```
data[data['Firstname'].str.len() >= 4]['Lastname']
```

should give you the desired output

Comment: Thanks for the short method @Ajey D.                 
    `data[data['FirstName'].str.len() >= 4]['LastName']`