# Preventing strings from getting parsed as NaN

Tags: pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv, nan, read.csv

I have a genetic data GSE99039،,include clinical data and rna of samples when I want to transform to csv some rows moved and pandas know them as NAN  ,how i can correct them. Value of each row place in correct row not in other rows. This problem happen in clinical data.

how I can read without NAN

Comment: Please provide an explicit and reproducible example of your data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to drop rows of Pandas DataFrame whose value in a certain column is NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-in-a-certain-column-is-nan)