# How to filter NaN values using Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, filtering, nan

Imagine the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A','B','C'], index = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'])
df.loc[['Monday', 'Friday'], ['A', 'C']] = 19
```

I want to print all columns and rows, that are not NaN. The output should be as follows:

|  | A | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Monday | 19 | 19 |
| Friday | 19 | 19 |

I have tried different methods, but none of them gives me the required result. I am doing something wrong here. Please help.

```py
df = df[df.isna()]
df[(df.iloc[::]) & (df.isnull() == False)]
```

Comment: `df.dropna()`..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to drop rows of Pandas DataFrame whose value in a certain column is NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413590/how-to-drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-whose-value-in-a-certain-column-is-nan)

Comment: What should be the output if you also set `df.loc['Tuesday', ['A', 'B']] = 19`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to remove rows/columns that are fully composed of NaNs use [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) on both axes:

```
out = df.dropna(how='all').dropna(how='all', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
         A   C
Monday  19  19
Friday  19  19
```

##### Timings

Comparison with `df.stack().unstack()` for a 1000x1000 DataFrame (50% NaNs):

```
# df.stack().unstack()
76 ms ± 3.73 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# df2.dropna(how='all').dropna(how='all', axis=1)
3.82 ms ± 84.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A','B','C'], index = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'])
df.loc[['Monday', 'Friday'], ['A', 'C']] = 19
print(df)
```

Output:

```
             A    B    C
Monday      19  NaN   19
Tuesday    NaN  NaN  NaN
Wednesday  NaN  NaN  NaN
Thursday   NaN  NaN  NaN
Friday      19  NaN   19
```

Add this to your code:

```
df = df.stack().unstack()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         A   C
Monday  19  19
Friday  19  19
```

Comment: Using `stack().unstack()` is a nice trick, but this performs unnecessary reshaping. You can achieve the same with `dropna`. If you have few NaNs, this will be much less efficient than `dropna`. It will also fail if you have duplicated column/indices.